# Update parent updatepanel from within usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, controls

I have an update panel that contains a repeater that calls a user control into each row. When I click a button inside the user control, the page does not refresh at all, only when I reload it completely. How can I make the update panel refresh from user control's button click?

Answer (score 3):

[Phairoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61029) is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224277/update-parent-updatepanel-from-within-usercontrol/1224907#1224314) that your button needs to successfully cause a PostBack.

There are three things that affect when a UpdatePanel is updated:

1. The `UpdateMode` property -   This takes two possible values, `Always` and `Conditional`.

   - If it is set to `Always` then any postback o the page will cause the UpdatePanel to update.
   - If it is set to `Conditional` then the UpdatePanel is only updated when the UpdatePanel's `Update` method is called or when one of the UpdatePanel's triggers does a postback.
2. The `Triggers` proroperty - Defines which controls will cause the UpdatePanel to be updated when `UpdateMode` is set to `Conditional`.
3. The `ChildrenAsTriggers` property -  This is a boolean value that determines if child controls of the UpdatePanel are automatically considered triggers without having to be added to the `Triggers` collection.

Because your button is in a UserControl it won't be easy to add the control to the `Triggers` collection or to have the button call the Update method on the UpdatePanel that is not inside the UserControl.

Because your UpdatePanel contains the UserControl's your best bet is to enable `ChildrenAsTriggers`.  If this doesn't work try setting the `UpdateMode` property to `Always`.  If this still doesn't work then [Phairoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61029) is probably [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224277/update-parent-updatepanel-from-within-usercontrol/1224907#1224314) and your Button isn't posting back.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes solving this problem not really convenient with Triggers. So here is another fancy approach which could be used even from your user controls without any knowledge about Update Panel:

```
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    if (scriptManager != null) 
        scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(SomeControlID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your buttons on your user control are attempting to do a postback?  I haven't used update panels in a while (and I'd actually recommend avoiding them) but if I recall correctly they will refresh whenever a postback is done within them.  This means that your buttons must be Asp:Buttons (or similar controls that cause postback) and not have some kind of javascript on them that would not allow their action to continue (such as a return false).